# Adding users to Activiti using a timer event

Tags: java, timer, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

I'm trying to add users to my Activiti identity service. I need to add these users at a regular interval so I thought I'd create a simple BPMN 2.0 process using timer event and use that as my scheduler. I tested this "scheduler" process using simple log statements, the process works fine. However, when I add the real code to save users, Activiti seems to be re-invoking the process for each user being added. So if I add three users, after the timer event times out, my Java method also gets called three times.

Here's a snippet of the method being called in the service task:

```
User user = identityService.newUser(identifier);
user.setFirstName(firstName);
user.setLastName(lastName);
user.setEmail(emailId);
user.setId(userId);
identityService.saveUser(user);
```

I have tested this code with JUnit by itself and it works fine. No issues adding users. The problem is only when this is being called from an Activiti process.

Here's my BPMN 2.0 process:

[image: BPMN 2.0 Process]

I went through Activiti's `saveUser` method to understand what it is doing internally. It is creating two events on inserting a user `ActivitiEventType.ENTITY_CREATED` and `ActivitiEventType.ENTITY_INITIALIZED`. I'm not sure if this is causing it to trigger the process again.

I'm new to Activiti, so could be something simple that I'm missing. Any help would be really appreciated.